# How to custom NavigationRail for alignment, splash, and etc

Tags: flutter

[image: current widget]

From this image, you can see this Icon does not stay at the center of this button area(notice the splash color.). I want to make it stay at the center with this code but it is not working.

```
selectedIcon: Center(
        child: Tooltip(
          message: e.name,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: iconHeight/2,
              height: iconHeight,
              child: Center(
                child: Icon(e.selectedIcon),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      label: Text(e.name),
    );
```

And I want to remove this splash color when clicking. I tried to cover the NavigationRail with Theme widget but it's not working. (It still has the grey color)

```
Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
              ),
              child: NavigationRail(
```

And I want to fix this icon button area size but I can only fix height. I tried to set the width for the icon widget but nothing changed.

I feel it is hard to customize this widget, should I desire to customize it with the Row and Column widget?